# Unable to update ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: updates

I have been unable to update my distro for a while now. When I attempt to do so, I get the following message bit: `Failed to download repository information` and then the following details, which is just a small snippet of the giant readout I get every time I attempt an update:

```
W:Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick-backports/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
W:Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick-backports
```

If anyone can help me fix this, I'd very much appreciate it; this is maddening.

Answer (score 0):

---edited to use gui---
go to Software Sources (or look under repositories in the package manager)
deselect everything.  Go to 'third party' tab.  or 'other software' whatever it is called in your version.  Deselect all here too.  now use the add button and add
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick main restricted universe multiverse
now close it and hit the reload button.

use update manager for upgrade or from terminal

sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade